# Existence of a non null linear continuous function

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be normal vector spaces and $L_c(X,Y)$ the space of all the linear continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$. When can we assert $L_c(X,Y) \ne \{ 0 \}$ ? Here is what I know so far.

- If $X$ is of finite dimension we have $L_c(X,Y) = L(X,Y) \ne \{0\}$ (assuming $X \ne \{0\}$).
- If $Y = \mathbb{R}$ by the Hahn-Banach theorem there exists $H$ a closed hyperplan containing $\{0\}$ what yields the existence of a non null linear continuous function of $X'$.

In the general case I don't see how to proceed, any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is a non-zero continuous linear functional on $X$ and $y$ is any non-zero element of $Y$ then $Tx=f(x)y$ defines a  non-zero element of $L_c(X,Y)$.

Existence of $f$: Take any nozero $x_0$ in $X$ and define $f$ on the one-dimensional space $M$ spanned by $x_0$ by $f(cx_0)=c$. Then $f$ is a  continuous linear functional on $M$ and Hahn-Banach Theorem tells you that you can extend it a continuous linear functional on $X$. This works for real as well as complex scalars.

Comment: Thanks. But I see how $X'$ is non reduced to $\{0\}$ when $X$ is real but not complex, do you know how to see it?

Comment: @blamethelag I have edited my answer to address your question.